# how to connect to aws bastion host with terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2

help! our devops created a bastion host with terraform and I don't understand how to connect.  We've been talking back and forth all day and getting nowhere.  He asked me for my pub key, I provided it.  When I try to connect with `ssh -i mykey.pub ec2-user@mydomain.com`, it doesn't work.  Our devops is asking me why I'm connecting to that host when I'm the bastion server (?!?).   This doesn't make sense he's expecting me to connect to `ubuntu@myip`, but that doesn't work and I don't understand why it would because how would it know which AWS server to connect to?  I asked for an AWS pem key but he said I need to use my pub key.

I've been trying to find documentation online that would explain how I'm supposed to connect (I'm on macos) but all documentation shows that an AWS pem key is required.

Comment: You generate key pair (public and private). Then you give them the public key, but you use private key when connecting (`... -i mykey.priv ...`). They should provide you ip address or hostname to connect to.

Comment: "They should provide you ip address or hostname to connect to", that's what I'm expecting too, but he's telling me he can't give me the hostname because I'm the bastion host, I need to use myUserName@myIp.  This doesn't make sense to me, but our devops is an AWS certified architect, he knows what he's doing.

Comment: Well, if they can't help you, then I suggest you ask someone else, and carefully re-read your back and forth communication. If I was AWS architect/engineer and one of my colleagues still can't connect after trying all day, I would feel that is my responsibility.